# What other options apart from C2DM to use a web server to configure android app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-c2dm

I have an app that has some configuration settings stored in SharedPreference. Now I want to provide a web interface using which customers can log into their account through a browser on the web and change the config settings seamlessly. These changes should be pushed to my android app..

I know C2DM is one option but I dont want to rely on :

1. If Google Market app is installed on my customer's app.
2. If they have configured a google account linked to their phone(It uses an existing connection for Google services. This requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. source : http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/android/c2dm/)

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess C2DM implementation with a broadcast receiver would not be such a bad idea. SMS are costly and implementing my own notification system couldnt be more battery power efficient than google's.

My concern of customers not having Google Play or an account linked to their phone will be taken care of based on the fact that anyways they will be downloading my app from the market and that makes them have the two requirements met.

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications there is another one better service:  [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)

Comment: Well, the functionality needs something more than just notification. I need to push the settings that will update the sharedPreferences of the app. Also, I am looking for a solution using Google API's and not a third party tool